# No idea why this login script isn't working!

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I was following a tutorial I found on how to create a simple login using sessions and a database. I followed it to the T (with the exception of tidying up all of the code because theirs was a mess and I'm OCD like that).

I get no errors at all on the page, it just comes up with a blank screen and I can't work out for the life of me why it's doing. I've been trying to get it working for the best part of about 3 hours.

There are 4 files:

1. index.php - Contains the form for the login script
2. login.php - Where the form data is processed, which is "require_once"'d into the index.php page at the very start.
3. config.php - Database connection info
4. cpanel.php - Where I want the user to be sent once they logged in

And here are those 4 files in *action* (although I guess they're not in action since they don't actually work!):

[index.php](http://albion.chrishdunnevstheworld.com/cms/index.php.txt)
[login.php](http://albion.chrishdunnevstheworld.com/cms/login.php.txt)
[config.php](http://albion.chrishdunnevstheworld.com/cms/config.php.txt)
[cpanel.php](http://albion.chrishdunnevstheworld.com/cms/cpanel.php.txt)

[And here's the tutorial I used.](http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/login_logout/)

[Lastly here's a link to the original (non-source) index.php file](http://albion.chrishdunnevstheworld.com/cms/)

Hope you guys can help, it's driving me crazy now.

Comment: I get a login screen when I click the last link provided.  Also, a quick scan of the login.php code makes it seem highly likely that SQL injection is possible with this code.  Might want to read up on how to prevent that.

Comment: Chrome Developer tools might give you a clue. :)

Comment: You have what appears to be a basic trouble-shooting exercise.  Make sure you are set up to have errors displayed; hopefully you are actually trying this out on a dev server (W/X/LAMP).  Beyond that, I would just suggest you check your file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
if($jackin) {
```

to

```
if(isset($jackin)) {
```

in login.php file

Also put `ini_set('short_open_tag',1)`

in your cpanel.php file if short_open_tag is disabled in php.ini

Comment: This worked thanks! However ini_set('short_open_tag',1) gave me an error, taking it out fixed it. I changed the <? tags to <?php, which I prefer to use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should try error_reporting(E_ALL); for additional Error output. Check all POST Variables with an echo() / var_dump(), Check the Ifs also with echo() and make sure thats everything is OK.
The echo for $error is doubled.

Additional you should not use the Location Element on the Header with an relative Path.

Comment: why can't you use relative paths in `header("location:")`? I don't think that's right.

Comment: Because the HTTP1.1 Spec for Location says so, the most Clients accept it relative but its not HTTP1.1 Spec conform see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: I'll look into it further tomorrow, nearly finished work now so I can finally put it down. Thanks for the advice, any more suggestions are extremely welcome!